# How to calculate the height difference between two curves?

Tags: python, data-science, curve-fitting, curve

I have two curves for past data eg. I have cumulative curves for 2013 and for 2014. How to calculate the delta difference between these two curves and propagate this delta difference to the future curves for  2015, 2016, 2017...?
I am using Python to find fit for the curves 2013 and 2014 but I am not sure how to propagate the difference between these two curves for 2015?

Note: I don't have enough data for 2015, so I am using this delta difference as a forecast for 2015

I have fitted the curves using Spline regression and have the fitted curve for matured data for 2013 and 2014. I am using this link https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/03/introduction-regression-splines-python-codes/

and using Cubic spline regression for fitting curves for year 2013 and 2014

Comment: Can you show some code that you have already tried on your own?

Comment: No , I haven't written a code for it..That's what I am hoping to do!!!

Comment: Would you please post, or link to, the data for 2013 and 2014?